# Oracle 18c multiple insert errors

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

I need to complete multiple insert in Oracle table about 100k rows. But when I try do like this:

```
insert into  table_name (ID, code, date_t)
values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '232323232323'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into  table_name (ID,  code, date_t)
values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '242424242424'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

I'm getting an error :

```
ora-00933 sql command not properly ended
```

I tried to make it using insert all:

```
insert ALL
INTO table_name (ID, code, date_t)  values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '232323232323'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
INTO table_name (ID, code, date_t)  values (schema_name.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL, '242424242424'  , to_date('2020-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
SELECT 1 FROM schema_name.table_name;
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated
```

How can I solve that errors or How can I make multiple insert in oracle?

Comment: 1. [Multitable insert](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9015.htm#i2095116): *A multitable insert is considered a single SQL statement. Therefore, the first reference to NEXTVAL generates the next number, and **all subsequent references in the statement return the same number*** 2) Command should end with semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with those inserts.

```
SQL> desc table_name
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 CODE                                               VARCHAR2(20)
 DATE_T                                             DATE

SQL> INSERT INTO table_name (ID, code, date_t)
  2          VALUES (scott.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL,
  3                  '232323232323',
  4                  TO_DATE ('2020-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO table_name (ID, code, date_t)
  2          VALUES (scott.SEQ$table_name.NEXTVAL,
  3                  '242424242424',
  4                  TO_DATE ('2020-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, it must be the way you're running those inserts. Let me guess: if it is TOAD and there's no empty line between each `insert`, it'll return `ORA-00933` so "solution" is to execute them as a script (`F5`).

Some other GUI might require different action.

So - how exactly are you running those commands?

Comment: Thanks, It's working when I execute it as a script. Was using dbeaver

Comment: But how is this possible to do using a console? People can't understand how to complete it as a script

Comment: Which "console" is it? DBeaver's? I don't use that tool so I can't answer the question. Why do "people" run those INSERT statements? Which people? What's to "understand"? Instruct them to run it *as a script*.